# Getting segmentation faults when working with any file input/output

Tags: c

I'm writing some code to take a file I've already created, testfile.txt, and writing the same text into a different file, but changing the periods (.) to exclamation points (!)..

I've been getting a segmentation fault that has to do with the file pointer, so I wrote it to just type ERROR instead if the pointer returns NULL.

I feel like it has something to do with my directory, but I have not really worked with my mac terminal before and just run the code from a text editor with a plugin.

```
int main(){
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *fp2;
  fp = fopen("testfile.txt", "r");
  fp2 = fopen("testfileout.txt", "w");
  if(fp == NULL || fp2 == NULL){
      printf("ERROR");
      return -1;
  }

  char ch;
  while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
    if(ch == '.'){
      ch = '!';
    }
    fputc(fp2, ch);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  fclose(fp2);

  return 0;
}
```

This is the code for reference.
It is returning "ERROR"

Comment: Note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an **`int`**. This is actually important for that `EOF` check.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Learn to use [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: As for the `ERROR`, first separate the `fopen` checks so you know *which* one failed. Then print the result of `strerror(errno)` to see what the error is.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Isn't the point of fgetc() to return characters it's reading from the file?

Comment: Error : fp , no file or directory @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Yes `fgetc` reads a character, but it returns an `int`. This is because `EOF` is an `int` value, and comparingan unsigned `char` with an `int` will not work well (it's implementation defined if `char` is signed or unsigned). This problem is because `char` is commonly *promoted* to `int` for just about all operations (including when comparing to an `int`), and then it will be *sign extended*. The unsigned `char` value `0xff` (`-1` with two's complement) will then become `0x000000ff` which is *not* equal to `-1` (`0xffffffff`).

Comment: As for the error you get, it should be simple to figure out: Your program can't find the file `testfile.txt` in the "current working directory" of the program. How do you run your program? Where is the file `testfile.txt` located compared to the executable file?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't really know how to figure that out. All my c files and .txt files are in my documents, but I run my code not directly from terminal, but from a text editor with a compiling plugin installed that does it all for me.

Comment: Then you need to configure your editor settings for building/running to set the "current directory" or "working directory" (or similar, read the documentation for your editor and its settings) to be the location where your text files are located.